# Define an empty default constructor with no default constructible data member

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, regular-type

Consider the following example:

```
class MyWrapper {
    public:
        MyWrapper() {};
    private:
       ThirdPartyLibraryType impl;
};
```

Suppose that `ThirdPartyLibraryType` has no default constructor and I can't help it since it is a third party library type. Then this code will not compile since the default constructor `MyWrapper()` must call the default constructor of `ThirdPartyLibraryType`. Now I just want the default constructor to do nothing, because my use case for using the default constructor is the following:

```
std::array<MyWrapper,10> myArray;
for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    myArray[i] = generateMyWrapper(...);
}
```

Is there a way to force the generation of a default constructor ? (With no overhead, I do not want to use the obvious solution of having a `ThirdPartyLibraryType*` has a data member)

**Edit:**
Until now, I used an approach similar to the one proposed by Yakk, that does not rely on the default constructor, but I think the case of a member function call is ugly:

```
template<class T, size_t N, class C, class CF>
std::array<T,N> gen_array(C const& obj, CF&& f) {
    ...
    use obj.f
    ...
}

class MyClass {

    MyWrapper generateMyWrapper(int i) const { ... }

    auto genMyWrapperTypeArray() const {
        return 
            gen_array<
                 MyWrapper,10,MyClass,
                 MyWrapper(MyClass::*)(int) const
            > (
                *this, &MyClass::generateMyWrapper
            );
    }
}
```

I have not tested it, my point is, if the syntax is not exactly the same, it will still be much much more complicated than the simple for loop I would use if the default constructor was available.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, could you call the `ThirdPartyLibraryType`'s ctor with some default value? Such as `MyWrapper() : impl(some_default_value) {};`

Comment: If the focus is on initializing an array when there's no default constructor, why don't you simply switch to a vector ?  `vector<MyWrapper> myVector; for (int i=0;i<10;++i) myVector.push_back(generateMyWrapper(...));` ?

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes you can do that. There is two problems: 1: I don't know a valid some_default_value for the default constructor 2: the code is templated and `ThirdPartyLibraryType` refers to many different types with potentially different non-default constructors

Comment: @Christophe Yes I can do that but a vector is slower. However, maybe a type similar to std::array not enforcing default-construction of the elements is possible to implement...

Answer (score 1):

`std::experimental::optional` or boost equivalent has modest overhead, but deals eith "this may be or not constructed".

An unsafe equivalent would be `std::aligned_storage_t` where you drfer construction.  Problem is at destruction, you need to know if it is constructed.

A better option might be to optional the entire array, and not have a zero argument ctor at all.  Package up what you need to construct each argument and create a constructor taking that, instead of a loop.

```
template<class T, size_t...Is, class F>
std::array<T,sizeof...(Is)> gen_array(
  std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&&f
){
  return {{f(Is)...}};
)


template<class T, size_t N, class F>
std::array<T,N> gen_array(
  F&&f
){
  return gen_array(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, f);
)
```

The above calls the passed lambda with the index for each element to construct the element.

Comment: I think I a using the third solution you mention: I have a `MyArray` class with a ctor taking a generator as an argument. But it tends to become ugly in some cases, mostly when the function is actually a member function (ugly call syntax, handling of `this`...)

Comment: @b lambda makes it easy?  Use `[&](size_t i){ return blah;}`?

Comment: I edited my question for showing the member function case. Maybe I can improve the syntax with lambda but I don't know, I am not fluent at all with them.

Comment: @b call my array gen, pass the lambda, replace return blah with arbitrary code that in the end returns the array element.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Indeed the lambda makes it much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If `ThirdPartyLibraryType` has no default constructor, there are chances that this is due to a valid **design decision** / reason.

You then have two approaches:

- either you find some suitable parameters for a non-default constructor and you use these in your wrapper;
- or you delay the construction of your `ThirdPartyLibraryType`, until you know which of its constructors to use and with which parameters.

The first approach would look like:

```
class MyWrapper {
    public:
        MyWrapper() : impl(/*parameters that you've selected*/) {};
    private:
       ThirdPartyLibraryType impl;
};
```

Perhap's it suits your needs, because you already know which constructor parameters you want to use, or because you can afford constructing an inexpensive object and overwrite it later. But this is not always a good idea...

The second approach would use the pointer that you wanted to avoid.  This approach has many advantages:

- You can construct huge default-initialized arrays like in your example and overwrite the unexpensive default wrappers with the generated objects.
- You respect the design of the library you rely on, constructing only objects which make sense.
- You can reduce dependency to the thirs party library: compilation units that need your wrapper do not need to know the third party type, nor to include headers of the third party library ( a forward declaration is sufficient).

In fact the obvious pointer approach would make your wrapper implement the [PIMPL idiom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438477.aspx).

Comment: The default-constructed object won't be valid. My point is that it is going to get initialized just after in the loop. The alternative to make it valid when constructed is just difficult to implement and syntactically ugly (i'll post an example in a minute).

Comment: I agree that forcing a default when no default is foressen is ugly.  I tried to express it diplomatically (in fact in some rare case where it could help).  However either a member  belongs to the class and it needs to be constructed WITH the class' object, or you use a pointer.  In the meantime I've elaborated on this second approach as I think it would definitively make more sense when looking at your generating loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I a aware of the pimpl idiom but this is not what I what to achieve here. I also know that there are perfectly valid arguments not to make the default constructor available. I once thought these arguments were more important that the argument of convenience and flexibility in the control flow, but I don't anymore. Plus, if you look at people from the concept proposal, they seem to tell you that your object should be what they call `Regular` or `semiregular` which include default-constructible